# Dynamic initialisation of 3D array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 3-dimensional space X-Y-Z discretised into cells. Each cell has a certain density value associated with it. I want to be able to store the density values in a 3-D array so that I can recall them by index i.e.

`density_ijk = x[i][j][k];`

I have the following class definition:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a, int b, int c);

private:
    double ***x;
}

A::A(int a, int b, int c){
   x = new double**[a];
   for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        x[i] = new double*[b];
        for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
            x[i][j] = new double[c];
        }
    } 
}
```

It builds successfully, however at runtime `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)` is generated.

Is there a dangling pointer somewhere in my code? What could I be doing wrong?

My main is:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int numX=100, numY=100, numZ=10;

    A testImplementation(numX, numY, numZ);

    return 0;
}
```

Source 1: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83080/Dynamic-Three-Dimensional-Arrays-in-C-C-C-Java
Source 2: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/24347/

Thanks!

Comment: Being called a [three-star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) is usually *not* a compliment, quite the opposite. First of all, do you *really* need it? What problem is it supposed to solve ([related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/))? And why aren't you using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, The code wasn't copied correctly. it is `x[i][j] = ...`

Comment: Then you need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. How do you use the class? Do you pass instances of it around by value? Return instances of it by value? Do you follow [the rules of three or five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (if you use vectors you could have followed [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) instead)?

Comment: How big are a, b and c? You may run out of memory!

Comment: a=100, b=100, c=10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use owning raw pointers

```
class A {
public:
    A(std::size_t a, std::size_t b, std::size_t c);

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> x;
}

A::A(std::size_t a, std::size_t b, std::size_t c) 
  : x(a, std::vector<std::vector<double>>(b, std::vector<double>(c, 0.))) {}
```

If you want to fiddle with `a`, `b` and `c` first, write a method to do that.

```
class A {
public:
    A(std::size_t a, std::size_t b, std::size_t c);

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> x;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> fiddle_input(std::size_t a, std::size_t b, std::size_t c);
}

A::A(std::size_t a, std::size_t b, std::size_t c) : x(fiddle_input(a, b, c)) {}

std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> A::fiddle_input(std::size_t a, std::size_t b, std::size_t c) { 
    /*Some implementation*/ 
    return {new_a, {new_b, {new_c, 0.}}}; 
}
```

The compiler is allowed (and post c++17 **required**) to only construct one 3d vector with this return by value.

Comment: is there a way I can initialise x within the body of the constructor? This would also allow me to manipulate a, b, c based on a formula.

Comment: Alternately, call `A::A` with the fiddled parameters in the first place

Comment: A::A(int a, int b, int c) : x(a, {b, {c, 0.}}) {} Raises the error `Non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') in initializer list`

Comment: Hmm, probably worth changing `a`, `b`, `c` to `std::size_t`, and avoiding braced initialization